# How do I explain Schnorr signatures and signature aggregation to 7 year old cousin?

Tags: schnorr-signatures

How do I explain Schnorr signatures and signature aggregation to my 7 year old cousin?

Nathan Aw

Comment: There are no BIPs for Schnorr signatures or signature aggregation yet.

Comment: Hi Pietter, I have edited my question. Understand that schnorr signatures is in the technology roadmap though?